# Github Client Sync Issue

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I cannot get the GUI of GitHub client to sync to my GitLab remote. If I push or pull via Git Shell it's successful, but if I use the GUI sync button, I get "The repository doesn't seem to exist anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed." I began with an SSH connection, I've switched to a HTTPS. When I push via shell, it still asks me for my SSH password. Did I miss a change in the config?

Comment: What did you name the remote?

Comment: Apparently I forgot to hit the enter key when I put in the new remote name. So it was still using the SSH URL. I've fixed it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel I think you should [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/641451).